# C#: is there any clever way to eliminate this redundant code?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I inherited a C# ASP.Net Core (now .Net 5.0) project with a bunch of entities models like this:

```
   public class Foo
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(36)")]
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(36)")]
        public string RDoxFindingsID { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(36)")]
        public string LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastUpdatedAt { get; set; }
        public string F001 { get; set; }
        ...

   public class Bar
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public Guid ID { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(36)")]
        public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(36)")]
        public string RDoxFindingsID { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "varchar(36)")]
        public string LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastUpdatedAt { get; set; }
        public string Q100 { get; set; }
        ... <= The same "header" fields (CreatedBy, CreatedAt, etc. etc) are copied/pasted at the top of each different model
```

So my Create and Edit razor pages have a lot of duplicate code like this:

```
public class CreateModel : PageModel
{
    ...
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        Foo.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
        Foo.CreatedBy = Findings.CreatedBy;
        Foo.LastUpdatedAt = DateTime.Now;
        Foo.LastUpdatedBy = Findings.CreatedBy;
        _context.Foo.Add(Foo);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        Bar.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
        Bar.CreatedBy = Findings.CreatedBy;
        Bar.LastUpdatedAt = DateTime.Now;
        Bar.LastUpdatedBy = Findings.CreatedBy;
        _context.Bar.Add(Bar);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
       ...
```

Q: Is there any clever way I can refactor my C# code such that I can write *ONE* method I can call for *ANY* of these models?  Without copying/pasting each of these 4-6 lines over and over for each individual model?

NOTE: I *CANNOT* change the model.  But I can do whatever I want with the "Pages" code.

Comment: Why you cant change the model? Couldnt you let them implement a common interface?

Comment: Use an interface, if you cant, use reflection if you don't mind taking the performance hit, or if you like hard to diagnose runtime errors and wasting your time you can use `dynamic`

Comment: You could also get fancy with any of the above and use an interceptor and tags, however, I would strongly recommend against any such *tomfoolery*, this sort of abstracted side-affect will likely fail any sane code review. Just use an interface instead

Comment: Derive them from a common class. Get entity framework to set those props depending on which kind of action it wants to run (insert shall set created and updated, update shall changed update at, delete sets deleted at)

Comment: You still haven't provided good justification for why you "cannot change the model" - your inherited the project, you can do what the heck you like to it and this problem is caused by the original developer not knowing what polymorphism is, so fix the problem. (Which is the model)

Comment: You still haven't provided good justification for why you "cannot change the model"

Answer (score 1):

Here comes interfaces very handy, it's actually main use of them. Define common interface and use it. This should e something like this

```
class Foo : IEntity
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public string RDoxFindingsID { get; set; }
    public string LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdatedAt { get; set; }
}

class Bar : IEntity
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public string RDoxFindingsID { get; set; }
    public string LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdatedAt { get; set; }
}

//You can name whatever you want
interface IEntity
{
    Guid ID { get; set; }
    string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    string RDoxFindingsID { get; set; }
    string LastUpdatedBy { get; set; }
    DateTime LastUpdatedAt { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    public static async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(IEntity entity)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return Page();
        }

        entity.CreatedAt = DateTime.Now;
        entity.CreatedBy = Findings.CreatedBy;
        entity.LastUpdatedAt = DateTime.Now;
        entity.LastUpdatedBy = Findings.CreatedBy;
        _context.Foo.Add(entity);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    static async void Main(string[] args)
    {
        await OnPostAsync(new Foo());
    }
}
```

Comment: "*I CANNOT change the model*" - seems like a change to me, even if it is only a decoration

Comment: @TheGeneral: that's exactly my dilemma.  I'd *love* to use an interface - but that would require I change the model class.  Which, unfortunately, I cannot do.  Frankly, I'd implement the models differently, if I could ;)  PS: If this were good old C89, I'd probably just #define a macro ;)

Comment: Agree, I did not think that much tbh. So if I were you, I would go for reflection or dynamic. using dynamic is horrible practice tho

Comment: And also if two models in a project are basically the same just always use one of them

Comment: @Chestera: Thank you for your input.  They aren't the same. There's currently only one model "type" ("Foo"). I'm adding a second ("Bar"). There might ultimately be a dozen or more. Only the "top part" (CreatedBy, CreatedAt, etc) is "the same" - the subsequent fields are different for each model. If I were King, I'd normalize that "top part" into some "master" table. The "types" would have foreign keys to "master". But that's not an option. So I'm just trying to find an alternative to "excessive  copy/paste duplication" in my "Create.cshtml.cs" (and "Edit.cshtml.cs") Razor pages.